# What is the optimal autolyse time for sourdough?

Tags: baking, sourdough

I would like to know if there is a formula or technique for understanding the ideal/optimal conditions for dough autolyse?

I understand that different flours/grains have different absorption techniques and I understand calculations related to dough hydration.

I am trying to understand how a novice baker like myself can determine when autolyse is complete. Is it just by feel or is there a quantifiable metric that can be measured or determined based on flour type, protein levels, hydration, volume etc?

Or, is this one of the dark arts of sourdough baking?

Comment: While not answering your question directly (the question of ideal autolyse time is reiterated at the end of the article), [this article](https://www.kingarthurflour.com/blog/2017/09/29/using-the-autolyse-method) might give some insights into the pros and cons of, as well as some tips for optimizing, the autolyse period.

Comment: Note that autolyse works for any bread, not just sourdoughs.

Comment: @LSchoon irony - that was the exact article I have been reading which prompted my question. I will read the end again.

Comment: Haha, it _was_ the first thing I found on Google... I was referring to their statement "Is a longer autolyse more beneficial than a short one? More experimentation is necessary, but this may well vary from one recipe to the next."

Comment: I don't have a definite answer, but I can say that a 3-day long autolyse in the fridge was far too long.  Gluten development was shot (and this was bread flour with extra gluten added), and I suspect prolonged protease activity was the culprit.